# Find and delete latter duplicate records

Tags: php, mysql, sql, duplicates

I have a table that has 0.5 to 1 million records approx. The table has duplicate records by a varchar field.

Something like

```
ID int(11)
TITLE varchar(100)
```

There are many records that have duplicate TITLE values.

I need to remove the duplicate records. The first step is to find them. I suppose there are two methods:

1. To use `GROUP BY TITLE HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`
2. Go record by record using `SELECT ID, TITLE FROM MY_TABLE` and then for each record use a `SELECT ID FROM MY_TABLE WHERE TITLE='".$row['TITLE']." AND ID <> '".$row['ID']."'`

The question is that which method is efficient?

Or is there another more efficient method?

I am using php as the base language.

Comment: Which one do you want to delete ? latter or the former?

Comment: later will be fine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**In order to delete all duplicate records (having same title) you can use this query:**

```
DELETE B
FROM your_table A 
INNER JOIN your_table B ON A.TITLE = B.TITLE AND A.ID < B.ID.
```

This query will delete all the latter duplicate records while keeping the first one.

---

**In order to keep the latest while deleting all the previous duplicate records:**

```
DELETE A
FROM your_table A 
INNER JOIN your_table B ON A.TITLE = B.TITLE AND A.ID < B.ID.
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to see which latter (duplicate) records will be deleted before executing the delete operation run the following query:

```
SELECT B.*
FROM your_table A 
INNER JOIN your_table B ON A.TITLE = B.TITLE AND A.ID < B.ID.
```

---

> This assumes that all NEW ID's will be greater than than prior ID's. A
>   pretty safe assumption but caution is warranted

Thanks @xQbert for this addition.

Comment: Is there a way to see which records will be deleted before I run the actual delete... may be SELECT B.* ... will do that?...

Comment: Please check the updated answer under **edit** section.

Comment: I think this is a useful answer, I will give it a try and then accept... thank you

Comment: This assumes that all NEW ID's will be greater than than prior ID's.  A pretty safe assumption but caution is warranted.

Comment: Thanks @xQbert. I appreciate your effort.

Comment: This worked great... and also the new IDs are greater than prior so it works... thanks for the tip though @xQbert

Answer (score 0):

Use the below sql

```
DELETE FROM MY_TABLE WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT MIN(x.ID) FROM MY_TABLE x GROUP BY x.TITLE);
```

Comment: I understand the inner most query that it gives all the ids that should not be deleted, whether they are duplicate or not duplicate... but I do not understand 2 things... 1st is that why use another `SELECT * FROM (...) y`...? and 2nd is that why use x. in the inner most query... ?

Comment: There was some error when I use this query into 30M records. You can skip this part if you are not getting 1093 error.  

And, if you want to view the records which are going to delete using this query, just replace `DELETE` with `SELECT`in the same query and run the query.